# Python Openshift deployment

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, openshift

I'm trying to create an app in python 2.6 using openshift and rabbitmq cartridge to create simple send/receive. all my files work perfectly in the terminal but I can't open them in the web. Is there something I need to do in the wsgi/application.py file or do I have to cave in and use Django or Flask? I am unable to find any basic python examples anywhere!
Thanks

Comment: do yourself  favour and cave in

Comment: Seriously, you won't regret using a proper framework.

Comment: Just not sure if it's the best for what I am doing. But I guess i'll try it in django

Comment: Check out the Pyramid framework. I have several OS python/ pyramid apps running.

Answer (score 2):

You have to read http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/ to understand how to WSGI works.
Then you need to familiarize how to return WSGI-application instance of Django or Flask.

For example, django returns it for that way:

```
from django.core.handlers import wsgi
application = wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

OpenShift and other PaaS need to handle this instance to run your application properly.

Example Flask configuration for OpenShift:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os

virtenv = os.environ['OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR'] + '/virtenv/'
os.environ['PYTHON_EGG_CACHE'] = os.path.join(virtenv, 'lib/python2.7/site-packages')
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
   execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
   pass

from my_app.main import app_factory
from my_app.config import Config

application = app_factory(Config)
```

where `app_factory` returns Flask application instance.